# asp.net NetworkInformationException on sending mail - what can be the reason?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailing

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
smtp.Send(msgMail);
```

On second line sometimes this exception is thrown:

System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException:

with Message: "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately"

What does that mean? What can be the reason?

Mail sending in general is working most times.
It's a IIS7 Windows 2008 Server machine.

Thank you.

Edit:

I found something here:
http://www.thevbzone.com/modWINSOCK.bas

```
Public Const WSAEWOULDBLOCK = (WSABASEERR + 35)      ' A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
```

MSDN says about this error (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Resource temporarily unavailable.
>
> ```
> This error is returned from operations on nonblocking sockets that
> ```
>
> cannot be completed immediately,...

So, what does that mean actually? Should I just ignore the error, resend the mail...? thanks.

Comment: can you check the ErrorCode property and tell us what it is? This exception is thrown when a call to win32 method fails. Checking ErrorCode may help understand what went wrong.

Comment: Did you set the credentials in the mailsetting section of the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check ErrorCode property of NetworkInformationException and then find this error code in [this ms article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28VS.85%29.aspx). It gives to you more information about exception.